# Creating series of multiple Concave hulls at certain distance in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon-creation, geometry-generator, qgis-expression, concave-hull

Starting from a layer with point geometry, I apply the following function that creates the concaves polygon for each group of points of an attribute field (`"class"`):

```
concave_hull(
    collect(
    $geometry,
    group_by:="class"),
    0.02
)
```

With the following result:

[image]

I would like to draw a series of multiple concaves_hulls at a certain distance from the outer concaved polygon of each group. I am trying the following expression, but without success:

```
collect_geometries(
    array_foreach(
        generate_series (1, 3, 1),
            concave_hull(
                collect(
                $geometry,
                group_by:="class"),
                0.02
        )
    )
)
```

The goal would be to get the following geometry (I add a hand-drawn representation):

[image]

Comment: Create the concave hulls and then buffers with a negative tolerance. If you have lines, try Offset curve or Array of offset lines.

Comment: Have you tried buffering your concave hull?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this expression:

```
collect_geometries(
    array_foreach (
        generate_series (-4,0),
        buffer(
            concave_hull(
                collect(
                    $geometry,
                    group_by:="class"),
                    0.02
            ),
            @element * 10 -- change here interval distances between the lines
        )
    )
)
```

[image]

---

Variant: for varying distances (smaller near the hull boundary, larger towards the inside of the polygon), multiply again with `@element` and a negative coefficient: `@element * @element * -10`:

[image]